# Windows Python2.7 mysqldb installation error exit status 2

Tags: windows, python-2.7, mysql-python

I'm trying to install mysqldb for Python. I'm running "pip install mysql-python" and I keep getting this error:

```
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
creating build\temp.win32-2.7
creating build\temp.win32-2.7\Release
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,'fi nal',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fobui ld\temp.win32-2.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl _mysql.c
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

--------------------------------------
Failed building wheel for mysql-python
Failed to build mysql-python
Installing collected packages: mysql-python
Running setup.py install for mysql-python
Complete output from command c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-bu ild-nja4gr\mysql-python\setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install - -record c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-5htk1y-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile: running install
running build
running build_py
copying MySQLdb\release.py -> build\lib.win32-2.7\MySQLdb
running build_ext
building '_mysql' extension
C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe /c /nologo /Ox /MD /W3 /GS- /DNDEBUG -Dversion_info=(1,2,5,' final',1) -D__version__=1.2.5 "-IC:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2\include" -Ic:\python27\include -Ic:\python27\PC /Tc_mysql.c /Fob uild\temp.win32-2.7\Release_mysql.obj /Zl _mysql.c
_mysql.c(42) : fatal error C1083: Cannot open include file: 'config-win.h': No such file or directory
error: command 'C:\Program Files (x86)\Common Files\Microsoft\Visual C++ for Python\9.0\VC\Bin\cl.exe' failed with exit status 2

--------------------------------------
Command "c:\python27\python.exe -c "import setuptools, tokenize;file='c:\users\scott~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nja4gr\mysql-python \setup.py';exec(compile(getattr(tokenize, 'open', open)(file).read().replace('\r\n', '\n'), file, 'exec'))" install --record c:\users\scott~1 .sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-5htk1y-record\install-record.txt --single-version-externally-managed --compile" failed with error code 1 in c:\users\scott ~1.sco\appdata\local\temp\pip-build-nja4gr\mysql-python
```

Would someone help? I am new to Python.

Answer (score 1):

That's because you have an Incompatible MySQL-C/Python connector for Python. Latest Connector comes only for Python3. 
Just follow these steps:

1. Download, [MySQL-C/Python27 Connector](http://cdn.mysql.com/Downloads/Connector-C/mysql-connector-c-6.0.2-winx64.msi)
2. Install it.
3. Open CMD as admin.
4. Type the following in CMD.

   - `mklink /d "C:\Program Files (x86)\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2" "C:\Program Files\MySQL\MySQL Connector C 6.0.2"`
5. Try installing now, `python -m pip install MySQL-Python`
6. TaDa! It works!
   This answer is from All of common comments in asked question of this type!

Answer (score 0):

1. Download **the 32-bit version** from [MySQL-C Download Page](http://dev.mysql.com/downloads/connector/c/6.0.html#downloads)
2. Try installing now, `python -m pip install MySQL-Python`

Worked perfectly for me. You have to install the 32-bit version even inside a 64-bit Windows environment.